# C: compare two strings one of them is from sscanf

Tags: c

I want to compare two strings i use a code similar to the following one but its not working

```C
int main (void){
  char function[100]="my_Name";
  char myType[50]={0};
  char myNumber[50]={0};
  sscanf(function, "%[^_]%*c%[^_]%s",myType,myNumber);
  if (myNumber=="Name")
  {
    //do stuff
  }
  return 0;
}
```

my `if`condition is not verified, How can I solve my problem?

Comment: hah, no `==` for strings, please. use `strcmp()`.

Comment: `if (strcmp(myNumber, "Name") == 0)`

Comment: :o did not though of it
Thks

Comment: Also always check return value of any `*scanf` functions, as a habit. It can save a lot of grief and grey hair.

Comment: How to check `*scanf` return value 
and what if i Want to do `switch(myType)` knowing that switch can take only interger walues ?

Comment: `"%[^_]%*c%[^_]%s"` requires three arguments for input. Argument is insufficient. This will probably cause segment faults.